# How best to handle large buffers in a layered protocol stack?

Tags: c, api, embedded, buffer

I am working on a simple protocol stack for a small embedded system (multidrop, rs485 type stuff). In this stack, losely models after OSI layers:

1. Application
2. Network
3. Datalink
4. physical (serial driver)

Each layer has its own header / footer portion that wraps the payload of the layer above it.

I will be using my own buffer pool of statically allocated fixed sized blocks to store the binary packets. (No malloc / free in this app.)

In other API's I have seen that the data is usually passed as a const pointer with an associated length. In this way the data would need a copy operation at each layer as the payload of the layer above is placed in a newly allocated buffer for the current layer.

For a three layer stack this would be 2 copy operations and 3 allocated buffers.

Is there a better way to do this and still maintain clean separation of the protocol layers?

To better anchor the discussion, lets say the packets are typically around 2k and the processor is a small 8 bit micro running at 8Mhz.

Comment: 8bit micro @ 8Mhz and and 2kB packet? You didn't mention the available ram but i would guess that the packet pretty much fills it and your clearly running a "single process" i guess i fail to see the reason to create so many layers and abstractions for such a simple system.  break it into "data transmission" and "application" and pass the payload via a pointer to a global.

Comment: @Mark, THe protocol stack is to be used on different platforms, one is an Atmega1281 with 8k ram. It can be clocked at 20Mhz, but we're not doing that for power reasons. I could relax the separation of concerns but that's not the point of my question.

Comment: @Mark, you're right about the 2k buffer, I most likely will not be able to go that large, but for this app the larger the better as it is high latency data channel (satellite) and I do not plan on adding windowing (as is done with TCP).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could avoid the copies by having each layer request an empty buffer from the next lower layer, rather than allocating one itself:

- Application Layer requests buffer
  length LA from Network Layer.
- Network Layer requests buffer length LA+LN from Datalink Layer.
- Datalink Layer requests buffer length LA+LN+LD from Physical Layer.
- Physical Layer pulls a buffer from the buffer pool.
- Physical Layer returns `buffer + phdr_len` to Datalink Layer.
- Datalink Layer returns `buffer + phdr_len + dhdr_len` to Network Layer.
- Network Layer returns `buffer + phdr_len + dhdr_len + nhdr_len` to Application Layer.
- Application Layer fills out data in provided buffer, and calls Network Layer to transmit.
- Network Layer prepends header and calls Datalink Layer to transmit.
- Datalink Layer prepends header and calls Physical Layer to transmit.
- Physical Layer prepends header and passes to hardware.

Comment: Or, the headers for the different layers don't need to be contiguous (in a single buffer): instead they could be in different buffers using a "scatter gather" API.

Comment: Thanks @caf, I was thinking about this as a possible solution as well. At the point of the get_buffer() call the upper layer would take responsibility of the buffer. There would need to be a free_buffer() on each layer in addition to a send(pbuf) in case something goes wrong so that the buffer can be freed properly.

Answer (score 4):

Create a buffer structure. With knowledge of the maximum size at the bottom layer, allocate enough buffer space at the top layer to prepend each successive layer as it goes down the stack. Each layer moves the pointer in the buffer structure as a layer is added.

At the bottom layer the start of the buffer is recorded in the pointer in the buffer structure. The data to be sent is in a contiguous buffer. No data was copied at each layer.

Going from bottom to top you peel off layers within the buffer structure.

Comment: This is the simplest approach, as it requires only one buffer, and no copying. For a slave device, the buffer is typically defined in the physical layer, as that's where messages originate.

Comment: And if you have different packet types you just refence structure pointer of another type.

Comment: The problem with this is that the top layer needs to know how much each lower layer needs, which is the tight coupling the OP is trying to avoid (I believe that's what the reference to "clean separation of the protocol layers" was about).

Comment: @caf: indeed. For slave devices, it's typically the _bottom_ layer which holds the buffer. This conveniently avoids the issue, as the maximum message size is often part of the bottom layer's specification. Where the top layer does have to hold the buffer, then this information does have to be known by the top layer. I suppose it's the lesser of two evils, if resources are limited!

Comment: The success of this approach is often dependent on how much control you have over the protocol stack and device drivers. I have worked on some low horsepower embedded systems where I had complete control over the protocol stack and drivers - avoiding the copy between threads/layers allowed us to boost throughput.

Answer (score 0):

> In other API's I have seen that the data is usually passed as a const pointer with an associated length. In this way the data would need a copy operation at each layer as the payload of the layer above is placed in a newly allocated buffer for the current layer.

I'm guessing you're giving an example of an API for a transmit buffer.

I think you can keep the same API, if you add the restriction that whoever invokes this API is not allowed to use or touch that buffer again until after they receive a subsequent notification that the transmit operation has completed: so that invoking the API is implicitly transfering ownership of that buffer.